# Cannot open .hlp files after upgrading to Windows 10 Anniversary Edition

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-10-v1607

Previously, in Windows 10, I was able to open .hlp files. Now, after I have upgraded to Windows 10 Anniversary Edition, I can no longer open .hlp files.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Exactly how do you try to open them? Exactly what happens when you do?

Comment: I for instance tried both, open help in an old IDE and open *.hlp files by double-clicking on them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to open .hlp files in windows 10, you must have a patched version of winhelp32.exe from windows XP in your c:\Windows folder.
If you could open .hlp's before, you must have had this file in your system.
Performing an upgrade would overwrite the c:\Windows folder, thus removing winhelp32.exe from your system.
Follow the directions at this link to inject winhelp32.exe into the proper location in Windows 10.
http://appuals.com/how-to-read-hlp-files-in-windows-10/

Answer (score 22):

I found a [solution](https://blog.spectologic.com/2015/09/09/using-hlp-files-in-windows-10/) that does not involve downloading any third-party utilities. Credit goes to Andreas Pollak for the original solution.

This answer assumes you are running a 64-bit US English version of Windows 10. You'll need to adjust the commands if you are using a 32-bit version or if you are in a different locale.

First, download [Windows8.1-KB917607-x64.msu](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=8cc63c95-edb3-4192-8a4a-aa4ce50cac7c) from [KB917607](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/917607/error-opening-help-in-windows-based-programs-feature-not-included-or-help-not-supported).

Then, in an **administrative** command prompt, switch to the folder containing the download and run the following commands. (You may find it easiest to run them one at a time.)

```
md ContentMSU
expand Windows8.1-KB917607-x64.msu /F:* .\ContentMSU
cd ContentMSU
md ContentCAB
expand Windows8.1-KB917607-x64.cab /F:* .\ContentCAB
cd ContentCAB
cd amd64_microsoft-windows-winhstb.resources_31bf3856ad364e35_6.3.9600.20470_en-us_c3a9a33a1aee3495
takeown /f %systemroot%\en-us\winhlp32.exe.mui
icacls %systemroot%\en-us\winhlp32.exe.mui /grant "%UserName%":F
ren %systemroot%\en-us\winhlp32.exe.mui winhlp32.exe.mui.w10
copy winhlp32.exe.mui %systemroot%\en-us\winhlp32.exe.mui
cd ..
cd amd64_microsoft-windows-winhstb_31bf3856ad364e35_6.3.9600.20470_none_1a54d9f2f676f6c2
takeown /f %systemroot%\winhlp32.exe
icacls %systemroot%\winhlp32.exe /grant "%UserName%":F
ren %SystemRoot%\winhlp32.exe winhlp32.exe.w10
copy winhlp32.exe %systemroot%\winhlp32.exe
```

After this you should be able to open .hlp files.

Comment: Thanks, this indeed worked but the `Find` tab was still missing; see my answer for the additional commands to bring that back as well.

Comment: The 'ren' and 'copy' commands fail for me with 'Access is denied'. I checked that I am running 'Administrator: Command Prompt'. I am running 'Windows 10 Pro version 1903'.

Comment: @NZD ensure you don't have the help viewer open

Comment: I can't have the help viewer open, because I don't have it ;-) That is what I am trying to install. I 'fixed' my problem by firing up WinXP in a VirtualBox.

Comment: @NZD I thought maybe somehow the existing `%systemroot%\winhlp32.exe` could have been running. For this type of scenario I would suggest using a tool like procexp to check for open handles on those files.

Comment: This is an outstanding answer. Note that it works now on Win10 64-bit Workstation (build 17763.775). Important note: Copy and paste the amd64_* folders directly from this post, as selecting the wrong one can bork things and cause you to backtrack to undo things and try again!

Comment: That worked for me. I had to correct certain folder names because my language is not 'en-us'. The `amd64_*none*` folder name was also different in my case

Answer (score 4):

@HolisticDeveloper's answer indeed worked to bring back `winhlp32.exe` on Windows 10. However, the `Find` tab was still missing so it wasn't possible yet to perform a full-text search of the help file. I've found that the following additional commands (also in an **administrative** command prompt) bring that back as well:

```
cd ..
cd amd64_microsoft-windows-winhstb.resources_31bf3856ad364e35_6.3.9600.20470_en-us_c3a9a33a1aee3495
copy ftsrch.dll.mui %systemroot%\syswow64\en-us\ftsrch.dll.mui
cd ..
cd amd64_microsoft-windows-winhstb_31bf3856ad364e35_6.3.9600.20470_none_1a54d9f2f676f6c2
copy ft*.dll %systemroot%\syswow64
```

Comment: I tried this but it didn't seem to work correctly. The `Find` tab appears and when I click on it I get the `Find Setup Wizard` dialog. However, once that completes I get the following error: "Unable to display the Find tab. (177)"

Comment: @HolisticDeveloper First of all my apologies for the late reply. Unfortunately all I can say is that it's working fine on my Windows 10 system (version 1903). May I suggest that you use Sysinternals' Process Monitor to check if any system DLLs are still missing? Have you tried with a different `.hlp` file?

Comment: @Holistic Developer In my experience, the “Unable to display the Find tab. (177)” error is fixed by deleting `.FTS`/`.GID`/`.CNT` files in the `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Help` directory. In earlier versions of Windows these were in the `%SYSTEMROOT%\Help` directory, so you may see the same advice elsewhere about this using that older path.

Comment: @Wolf It's unfortunately too long ago for me to remember where I found that information. It's very well possible that I just found it out myself, probably by checking `winhlp32.exe`'s behavior with Sysinternals Process Monitor.

Comment: BTW @TimDeBaets This is the indication I found in
`...\ContentMSU\ContentCAB\x86_microsoft-windows-winhstb_31bf3856ad364e35_6.3.9600.20470_none_be363e6f3e19858c.manifest` and
`...\ContentMSU\ContentCAB\amd64_microsoft-windows-winhstb_31bf3856ad364e35_6.3.9600.20470_none_1a54d9f2f676f6c2.manifest` respectively:
Line 29:
  `<file name="ftsrch.dll" destinationPath="$(runtime.system32)\" [...]`
Line 39:
  `<file name="winhlp32.exe" destinationPath="$(runtime.windows)\" [...]`
But I didn't find a reference for the symbolic `runtine.*` constants.

Comment: There is one tiny detail (or remark) that could be added to your answer: It has to be done within an administrator command prompt (whereas `takeown`, `icacls`, and `ren` operations are not needed since there are no `ftsrch.*` files in Win10 before).

Comment: I can confirm that it works (OS build 19044.1889), Since `winhlp32.exe` is a 32-bit program, it loads 32-bit DLLs and these go into the `SysWOW64` folder.

Comment: @Wolf thanks for the suggestion about administrator command prompt; I have updated my answer.

Comment: Excellent. That worked. I had to correct certain folder names because my language is not 'en-us'. The `amd64_*none*` folder name was also different in my case